# Expand hierarchical list's sections based on indent level

Tags: vba, excel

My current spreadsheet is set up with 2 columns - Description and Number. The Description column is set up as a hierarchical list where Variable 2 is a subsection of Variable 1, and Variable 3 is a subsection of Variable 2.

For example: Variable 1 as Continent, Variable 2 as Country and Variable 3 as City.

**Note:** The indentation is just for visual purposes and does not represent a change in column.

```
 Description          Number
 Variable 1A          Result
    Variable 2A       Result
      Variable 3A     Result
      Variable 3B     Result
    Variable 2B       Result
      Variable 3A     Result
      Variable 3B     Result
 Variable 1B          Result
    Variable 2A       Result
      Variable 3A     Result
      Variable 3B     Result
    Variable 2B       Result
      Variable 3A     Result
      Variable 3B     Result
```

I however would like my data to be split across the 3 description variables and appear like this in 4 columns:

```
 Description1     Description2    Description3    Number
 Variable 1A                                      Result
 Variable 1A      Variable 2A                     Result
 Variable 1A      Variable 2A     Variable 3A     Result
 Variable 1A      Variable 2A     Variable 3B     Result
 Variable 1A      Variable 2B                     Result
 Variable 1A      Variable 2B     Variable 3A     Result
 Variable 1A      Variable 2B     Variable 3B     Result
 Variable 1B                                      Result
 Variable 1B      Variable 2A                     Result
 Variable 1B      Variable 2A     Variable 3A     Result
 Variable 1B      Variable 2A     Variable 3B     Result
 Variable 1B      Variable 2B                     Result
 Variable 1B      Variable 2B     Variable 3A     Result
 Variable 1B      Variable 2B     Variable 3B     Result
```

Any help on how to build a excel VBA macro to do this would be very very helpful. I hope this makes sense. Thank you very much

Comment: What have you tried thusfar?

Comment: So the first column is actually indented though?  How exactly?  Is the spacing consistent/predictable?

Comment: How do you determine that your lower level variables are actually lower level variables and at what level they belong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that I should wait until OP puts forth more effort but this looked like a fun activity so I did it anyway.

It assumes that a section becomes a subsection of the previous section or a supersection of the following based on an `IndentLevel` difference of `2`, like this:

```
Variable 1A              IndentLevel = 2
   Variable 2A           IndentLevel = 4
      Variable 3A        IndentLevel = 6
   Variable 2B           IndentLevel = 4
Variable 1B              IndentLevel = 2
```

---

```
Option Explicit

Sub IndentOffset()

    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row

    Dim numbers As Range
    Set numbers = Range("B1:B" & lastRow)

    'push over the "Number" column
    numbers.Cut Destination:=numbers.offset(, 2)

    Dim indents(2) As String

    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Range("A2:A" & lastRow).Cells

        'copy sections over based on IndentLevel
        'assumes IndentLevel difference of 2 between sections

        Select Case cell.IndentLevel / 2

            Case 0
                indents(0) = cell.Value2

            Case 1
                indents(1) = cell.Value2
                cell.Value2 = indents(0)

                cell.offset(, 1).Value2 = indents(1)
            Case 2
                indents(2) = cell.Value2
                cell.Value2 = indents(0)

                cell.offset(, 1).Value2 = indents(1)
                cell.offset(, 2).Value2 = indents(2)

        End Select

        'reset the indent
        cell.IndentLevel = 0

    Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you- exactly what I wanted. Just amended the indent to multiples of 1 instead of 2. Also I realise this is not transposing but it was the closest thing I could think of for a "tag". Cheers